# Connect External Data into Snowflake with ODBC Driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I and my coworkers have recently started moving into Snowflake and have lots of datasources that connect through ODBC. We have gone through the documentation for Snowflake's ODBC driver, however we are stuck at the point immediately after setting up the driver. We now need to actually get the data into Snowflake, but there doesn't seem to be any information about how to do that... I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I just don't know enough to ask the right questions.

Do I need to write a script on my local machine that pushes stuff into Snowflake? Do I need to set up a local stage? Can I pull data directly through a Snowflake worksheet?

Any direction will help!

Comment: I’d start by reading the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/guides-overview-loading-data

Comment: @NickW the reason I posted a question is because the documentation does not cover the step right after setting up the ODBC. I'm hoping there is someone out there who has successfully set one up and would not mind sharing their insights.

Comment: Please provide a link to the step in the docs where the ODBC is set up and explain what you think the missing next step is

Comment: I would love to help @Skouzini - but the question is not clear: How much data? Only once, or looking to have a process constantly moving data? What about using S3 files instead?